# How to use eval() function with data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have a query like below.

```
let query= "VALIDATION_TYPE__INT32_value==1" 
let data = {};
data["VALIDATION_TYPE__INT32_value"] = 1;
var results = eval(query); 
Uncaught ReferenceError:` VALIDATION_TYPE__INT32_value is not defined
```

========================================================================

How will i send data eval() function?

Comment: `dictionaryData.VALIDATION_TYPE__INT32_value`

Comment: Welcome to SO! `{VALIDATION_TYPE__INT32_value = 5}` doesn't look right to me. Did you mean `:`? What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your 3rd line you are assigning a property value to the object `data`.

Therefore your 1st line should be comparing the value of that property, not a global variable:

```
let query= "data.VALIDATION_TYPE__INT32_value==1"
```

This change means that `result` will now equal `true`

---

Alternatively change your 3rd line to set a global variable, not a property of `data`:

```
VALIDATION_TYPE__INT32_value = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is misunderstand :

> let query= "VALIDATION_TYPE__INT32_value == 1";

Simple is not defined in global scope. We defined intro object data. Access also must be in data.

> data["VALIDATION_TYPE__INT32_value"] = 1;

Working example :

```js
let data = {};

let query= "data['VALIDATION_TYPE__INT32_value'] == 1";

data["VALIDATION_TYPE__INT32_value"] = 1;

if (eval(query) ) {alert("correct")} else {alert("its not 1")};
```